# How can I run an executable and take input from a text file on Linux?

Tags: c++

How can I run an executable and take input from a text file on Linux?
I was trying to use:
./(name of my executable) TextFile.txt but it does not work.

Comment: An what is your problem? Is you problem accessing the command line argument `TextFile.txt` in c++ or is the problem to read in the file. You need to add [mcve] of you c++ code to show what you did and where your exact problem is.

Comment: My problem is in accessing the command line argument TextFile.txt

Comment: They are stored in the `argv` of your main function (`int main(int argc, char *argv[])`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do ./(name of exe) < input.txt

and if you want to write the output to a text file you can do:

./(name of exe) > output.txt